# Python - Read CSV cell from specific row - row index is passed in variable

Tags: python, csv, python-behave

I'm using Python Behave to run automated tests against a web application.

There is a login page that takes a username and password.

The Behave scenarios have different login requirements, for example;

```
Given I am logged on as user1
Then do something
```

I created a csv file to hold the username and passwords for each login, but I'm having trouble getting it to read only the details that I want.

The csv file is like this;

```
 usertype,username,password
 user1,somename1,somepassword1
 user2,somename2,somepassword2
```

The required user is passed in the Behave step definition;

```
 @given('I am logged on as {login}')
```

I have tried the following implementation;

```
def do_login(context, login):
    driver = context.browser

    user_data = csv.DictReader(open('users.csv'))
    for row in user_data:
        row['user'] = login
        uname = row['username']
        pword = row['password']

        driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(uname)
        driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(pword)
```

But this just logs in with the first user in the table.

I don't know how to get it to select only the username and password corresponding to the login.

So for example, I pass the login as user2 and I want the username as somename2 and the password as password2.

I've read other questions relating to reading from csv files, but I couldn't find one that was the same as this.

I'm quite new to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should proof with an `if statement` in the `for loop` if the *usertype* matches the *login* before doing the `send_keys` method.

```
def do_login(context, login):
    driver = context.browser

    user_data = csv.DictReader(open('users.csv'))
    for row in user_data:
        row['user'] = login
        uname = row['username']
        pword = row['password']

        # something like this
        if login == row['usertype']:
            driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(uname)
            driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(pword)
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. It just tries to enter each username and password in sequence.

Comment: Yes, because of the for loop you're using. You have to iterate over a list and check if it's the right row at the moment. You can `break` then or you can use other data type like `dict` or something. But you have to iterate over CSV file anyway. There's no significant performance advantage I can see.

Comment: I've got it working now, with a slight change in your answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very much cleared with your question, but you can try this

Just read csv data in list of Dict format

```
user_data = csv.DictReader(open('users.csv'))
user_list = [d for d in user_data]
```

now you can use this data how you want as :

```
user_list[row_index][column_name]
```

I will suggest better to store you login information/Logs in any database system.

Comment: I've updated my original question with a snippet of the behave scenario. I want to login as a user specified in the scenario. In your answer, would the row_index and column_name relate to the usertype, username in the csv? So should I be able to do ['usertype']['username']

Comment: If you really want to use the [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) (that's another data type also mentioned in [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634396/python-read-csv-cell-from-specific-row-row-index-is-passed-in-variable/32634714#comment53225830_32634714)), you have to read it with the `fieldnames parameter`. It seems that you have a header with fieldnames in csv file, so you can omit *fieldnames parameter* and  access the resulting dict like this: d['username'] or d['password']. But you have to iterate anyway (for loop or list comprehension).

Comment: can do like that:-
user_data = csv.DictReader(open('users.csv')); 
user_list = {d.pop('user_type'): d for d in user_data};
now you can access value using user_list[user_type][column_name];